# Google Test separate project - How to get tests running against the C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, clion

I am trying to figure out how to run Google Test against my C++ project using CMake.  So far I have created a project called Simple and a Google Test project called SimpleTest.

**For the Simple Project**

Here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(Simple)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    main.cpp
    NewCppClass.cpp
    NewCppClass.h)

add_executable(Simple ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Here's my main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "NewCppClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    NewCppClass newCppClass;
    int i = newCppClass.getNumberToTest();
    cout << "i = " << i;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my Class Header:

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_NEWCPPCLASS_H
#define SIMPLE_NEWCPPCLASS_H

class NewCppClass {
    public:
        int getNumberToTest();

};

#endif //SIMPLE_NEWCPPCLASS_H
```

Here is my .cpp file:

```
#include "NewCppClass.h"

int NewCppClass::getNumberToTest() {
    return 5;
}
```

**For the SimpleTest Project**

Here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(SimpleTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    Main_TestAll.cpp
    MyFirstTest.cpp)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(SimpleTest ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(SimpleTest ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES})
```

Here's my Main_TestAll.cpp file:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Here is MyFirstTest.cpp file:

> Of course, this include must change when I figure out how to point to
>   my Simple project.

```
#include "this/package/NewCppClass.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

namespace {

// The fixture for testing class NewCppClass.
    class NewCppClassTest : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        // You can remove any or all of the following functions if its body
        // is empty.

        NewCppClassTest() {
            // You can do set-up work for each test here.
        }

        virtual ~NewCppClassTest() {
            // You can do clean-up work that doesn't throw exceptions here.
        }

        // If the constructor and destructor are not enough for setting up
        // and cleaning up each test, you can define the following methods:

        virtual void SetUp() {
            // Code here will be called immediately after the constructor (right
            // before each test).
        }

        virtual void TearDown() {
            // Code here will be called immediately after each test (right
            // before the destructor).
        }

        // Objects declared here can be used by all tests in the test case for Foo.
    };

// Tests that NewCppClass::getNumberToTest() is not equal to this fixed mumber.
    TEST_F(NewCppClassTest, ThisTestShallFail) {
        NewCppClass newCppClass;
        int i = newCppClass.getNumberToTest();
        EXPECT_EQ(i, 2);
    }

}  // namespace
```

**UPDATE:**

---

πάντα-ῥεῖ wrote this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30037879/1735836):

> I would recommend to put all the test case classes (as plain .cpp
>   sources) into a separate project, and link with the classes under test
>   from a separate library project. Include gtest_all.cc with the main()
>   function, or link against the gtest library, with the test project.
>
> To run the test cases add running the UnitTester artifact build from
>   that project as an additional build step.

I think this is the correct direction, so I'm adding it to the question as a reminder to myself and it may be helpful to others.

Also in below, written by πάντα-ῥεῖ:

> ...the classes under test should be bundled into a separate library
>   artifact, and linked to the test runner application.

I'm including all of this information here as I try to compile in my mind what needs to be done.

---

If I understand what needs to be done correctly, then I need to (in my C++ project) add to the CMakeLists.txt file to add GTest as an ExternalProject and add the tests in add_executable.  Something like this:

```
################################
# GTest
################################
include(ExternalProject)
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

################################
# Unit Tests
################################
# Add test cpp file
# Link test executable against gtest & gtest_main
add_executable(SimpleTest
    Main_TestAll.cpp
    MyFirstTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test GTest)
add_test( runUnitTests runUnitTests )
```

Comment: Here's some concise information IMHO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507723/how-to-start-working-with-gtest-and-cmake As mentioned in my previous answer, the classes under test should be bundled into a separate library artifact, and linked to the testrunner applicaiton.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I think I'm getting the gist.  Please bear in mind that I am new to C++ and CMake and GoogleTest.  There is a lot of information out there that is confusing more than helping.  So help me here, please.  "the classes under test should be bundled into a separate library artifact..." This means my C++ project, yes?  What do you mean by "bundled into a separate library artifact"?  "...and linked to the test runner application."  This means that the C++ project's CMakeLists.txt must include a section for including GTest and the Unit Tests.  Am I starting to get it right?

Comment: _"What do you mean by "bundled into a separate library artifact"? ""_ I meant you should create a separate library (static or shared) for the core classes you have (all those under test), and you link that one to either the test runner, or your _real (final)_ application target. There are more points to be considered: 1. Is the host system for the test runner the same as the target system? 2. Do you have user interactive code (GUI, terminal) input in those classes under test?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - For 1 and 2 NO!  I'm just trying to test one method in my C++ project.  So do you mean that I should have a test runner that links to GTest and my C++ project?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Do you mean that I should create a separate library where my classes are located in there as well as the C++ project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be the organization of your code modules. Supposed you have a c++ target project, that provides an executable program as it's final output:

- I suppose you want to create two executable artifacts

  - your final application
  - a test runner application that runs all test cases you have specified
- As for this should be your misconception, how to setup this scenario properly:
  **You cannot link functions from an executable artifact (the application) into another one (the test runner).**
- You can either

  - provide the core classes separate in a library and link it to your final application and the test runner. The application should provide a thin wrapper from the `main()` entry point.
  - add links to the sources for the classes under test, and completely compile them in the test runner environment

Comment: Hey, πάντα ῥεῖ:  I found a great tutorial on youtube for setting up GoogleTest with Make using NetBeans. I was really confused about the two projects thing and Bo Qian's tutorial makes it crystal clear.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TS2CTf11k1U&list=PL5jc9xFGsL8GyES7nh-1yqljjdTvIFSsh&index=1