# GoogleTest CMake doesn't recognize TEST_F: Like it's not recognizing GTest something

Tags: linux, cmake, makefile, googletest

OK, I admit it, this is a unique case.  When we build our application we are using make, so I've included my tests in a test folder under src.  Then at the same level as our release folder we have created a unit-test folder that includes all of our source files and our test source files.

But my IDE is CLion, which uses CMake.  In my CMakeLists.txt file, I have included:

```
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(TestProject ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(TestProject ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES})
```

I am creating my first Test Fixture.  Here is the code:

```
#include "OPProperties.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

namespace {
// The fixture for testing class OPPropertiesTestTest.
    class OPPropertiesTestTest : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        // You can remove any or all of the following functions if its body
        // is empty.

        OPPropertiesTestTest() {
            // You can do set-up work for each test here.
        }

        virtual ~OPPropertiesTestTest() {
            // You can do clean-up work that doesn't throw exceptions here.
        }

        // If the constructor and destructor are not enough for setting up
        // and cleaning up each test, you can define the following methods:

        virtual void SetUp() {
            // Code here will be called immediately after the constructor (right
            // before each test).
        }

        virtual void TearDown() {
            // Code here will be called immediately after each test (right
            // before the destructor).
        }

        // Objects declared here can be used by all tests in the test case for OPPropertiesTestTest.
    };


    TEST_F(OPPropertiesTestTest, ThisTestWillFail) {
        EXPECT_EQ(0, 2);
    }

}  // namespace


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Here is an image capture:

[image]

Notice the syntax checker errors in my TEST_F function.  When I started to type TEST_F code completion is trying to find a Boost Test Function.

Can someone tell me what else I need to add to the CMakeLists.txt file or what I am not doing that GTest functions are not being recognized?

Comment: Ohhh, I'm fairly no expert about CMake's `find_package`. In fact I miserably failed using it with `GTest`. But at all your test case source code looks OK for me. _"Notice the syntax checker errors"_ Do you have actual compilation errors with this code? GoogleTest and GoogleMock use some _esoteric_ template techniques, that are well suited to confuse several IDE's indexers and intellisense code checkers (I'm frequently experiencing the latter, when working on my test cases with Eclipse CDT Luna for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As πάντα ῥεῖ pointed out, I hadn't actually tried to build the code.  When I did I first received a linker error for pthread, so we added the following line the the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
target_link_libraries(OnePrint pthread)
```

Then I tried again to build and received these errors:

```
/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/home/user/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, I ran a search on these errors and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21116622/1735836).

The answer that worked for me was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28553527/1735836).